# @Bean initialization - difference between parameter injection vs. direct method access?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-bean

If a service bean depends on another: is there any difference between injecting that bean as a method parameter, or fetching from the method reference directly?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
   @Bean
   public SomeService some() {
      return new SomeService();
   }

   @Bean
   public AddService add(SomeService some) {
      return new AddService(some);
   }

   //alternative:
   //@Bean
   //public AddService add() {
   //   return new AddService(some());
   //}
}
```

Comment: When you use `@Configuration` there is no difference.  Read this please: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

There is no difference, but the first method is preferable.

**Long answer**

You don't work with a `MyConfig` instance, you implicitly interact with an in-memory subclass generated by [**cglib**](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) and backed by Spring's package [`org.springframework.cglib.proxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/proxy/package-summary.html) (with classes like [`Enhancer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.html), [`MethodProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy.html), etc.).

As debugging might reveal, they usually are called `ClassName$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$XXXXXXXX` or something.

When [`BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) starts initialising beans, it already works with cglib proxies. Proxies' methods are constructed to meet Spring's requirements (e.g. each call of a `@Bean`<strike>`@Scope("singleton")`</strike> method will return the same instance).

It makes possible to declare inter-bean dependencies. In the second method, we use `some()` or `this.some()` knowing that it will be referring to a proxy method at runtime.

*Why would I recommend the first approach?*

You immediately see what dependencies are required for a bean - they all are listed in the signature.