# Spring boot quartz schema other than public doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am not able to use other schema (than public) for quartz tables. This is my quartz setup:

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=2000
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
```

And config class:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext, DataSource dataSource, QuartzProperties quartzProperties) {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(quartzProperties.getProperties());

    schedulerFactoryBean.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setQuartzProperties(properties);
    schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    return schedulerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public Scheduler scheduler(ApplicationContext applicationContext, DataSource dataSource, QuartzProperties quartzProperties)
    throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory(applicationContext, dataSource, quartzProperties).getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    return scheduler;
}
```

This works fine, and the tables are getting created. However I would like to have the tables in a different schema. So I set quartz to use 'quartz' schema.

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=quartz.QRTZ_
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
[ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block] [org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It was a bold hope that "tablePrefix" can also adjsut the "db schema", (and there is no [documented property](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) concerning "db schema"), but you could get more lucky, if you configure it on the datasource.
i.e. you would introduce/configure different (spring) datasource( bean)s for every user/schema used by your application ...

- (like here:) [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337582/592355)
- [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360877/592355)

, then you'd [wire](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire) the scheduler factory with the appropriate datasource (`quartz`).

```
schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(quartzDataSource);
```

Or via (`@Autowired`) parameter injection, or method invocation : [@Bean initialization - difference between parameter injection vs. direct method access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51522278/592355)

##### UPDATE (regarding "wiring"):

..from [current spring-boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.quartz):

> To have Quartz use a `DataSource` **other than the application’s main `DataSource`**, declare a `DataSource`bean, annotating its `@Bean` method with [`@QuartzDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzDataSource.html). Doing so ensures that the Quartz-specific `DataSource` is used by both the `SchedulerFactoryBean` and for schema initialization.
> Similarly, to have Quartz use a `TransactionManager` other than the application’s main ... declare a `TransactionManager` bean, ...`@QuartzTransactionManager`.

---

You can take even more control by customizing:

```
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema 
Database schema initialization mode.
default: embedded (embedded|always|never)

spring.quartz.jdbc.schema 
Path to the SQL file to use to initialize the database schema.
default: classpath:org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_@@platform@@.sql
```

... properties, where `@@platform@@` refers to your db vendor.

But it is useless for your requirement... since [looking at](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore)
and complying with the original schemes - they seem schema independent/free. (So the data source approach looks more promising, herefor.)

REFS:

- https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html
- [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337582/592355)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360877/592355
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire
- [@Bean initialization - difference between parameter injection vs. direct method access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51522278/592355)
- [`spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema)
- [What are the possible values of spring.datasource.initialization-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53922279/592355)
- [`spring.quartz.jdbc.schema`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.quartz.jdbc.schema)
- https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.quartz
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzDataSource.html

Comment: I've upvoted your answer as it brings valuable information.
Still, I got the idea with tablePrefix=schema.tablePrefix from stack overflow research,
It seems it works for other people. 
EG.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045340/how-to-set-the-database-schema-for-the-quartz-scheduler-with-spring-boot-and-fly
Can't find the exact example.
Maybe someone found a workaround

Comment: thank you for upvote and interesting facts! ...s i tried, but didn't emphasize enough: all of these user/schema/data source "things" are very vendor-specific. *And* the (datasource) [`default_schema`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2737420/592355) + initialization details are of course relevant. .. On what (kind of) db do you operate?

Comment: and (looking again at the [built-in schemes](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore)) we must realize that any other table_prefix than `QRTZ_` should fail (using that scripts)

Comment: I'm using postgres. I even saw someone using Quartz.NET and said the 'hack' with tablePrefix worked.

Comment: Found a workoaround. Will let flyway create the scripts in the diferent schema, left the tablePrefix=schema.QRTZ_. Works as a charm

Answer (score 2):

So the idea is that Quartz doesn't create the tables using `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix`

Table names are static. Eg qrtz_triggers. as @xerx593 pointed out.

What we can do is to create the tables (manual, flyway, liquibase) in a different schema, update tablePrefix=schema.qrtz_ and it will work.

Tested with Postgres